# Plot a line between 2 points in a graph

Tags: matlab

I am plotting a graph as `plot(m,n,'o')`. In this graph, graph i again need to plot a line between 2 points.

Already tried:

```
plot(m,n,'o',[10 10],[100 70])
```

The second part is just giving me the points .What i need is a straight line that connects the 2 points.

Comment: what is in `m` and `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
m = 1:10;
n = rand(1,10);
plot(m,n, '-o')   % plot a normal line and circles at marker points
```

the **'-o'** is a combination of:

- **'-'**   defines a normal line
- **'o'** that defines circles at marker points.